# amazon products advertising api in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, amazon-product-api

I want to develop window phone 8 application. I am new to window phone 8 application.I want to confirm that can i use amazon's products advertising api in windows phone 8 app? the problem I am getting is that i am not able to reference **IClientMessageInspector** interface as i did it in web application

```
  public class AmazonSigningMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
    private string accessKeyId = "";
    private string secretKey = "";

    public AmazonSigningMessageInspector(string accessKeyId, string secretKey)
    {
        this.accessKeyId = accessKeyId;
        this.secretKey = secretKey;
    }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        // prepare the data to sign
        string operation = Regex.Match(request.Headers.Action, "[^/]+$").ToString();
        DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
        string timestamp = now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
        string signMe = operation + timestamp;
        byte[] bytesToSign = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signMe);

        // sign the data

        byte[] secretKeyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey);
        HMAC hmacSha256 = new HMACSHA256(secretKeyBytes);
        byte[] hashBytes = hmacSha256.ComputeHash(bytesToSign);
        string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);


        // add the signature information to the request headers

        request.Headers.Add(new AmazonHeader("AWSAccessKeyId", accessKeyId));
        request.Headers.Add(new AmazonHeader("Timestamp", timestamp));
        request.Headers.Add(new AmazonHeader("Signature", signature));
        return null;
    }

    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This interface is not supported in Windows Phone 8.

It's a very simple interface though so you could recreate it.

Comment: so there would be no problem creating the windows phone 8 amazon app from start to finish?

Comment: it is sort of confusing that after researching almost all the things on console getting stuck on the first step when started doing work on windows phone in visual studio.

Comment: I can't say if there would be other issues but if you're just missing an interface it would be easy enough to create. The API just looks to be all XML over a REST interface so all should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Amazon policy, you can not develop application for mobile phone or other handheld device using Amzon Product Advertising API
please refer to below link.
https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/agreement.html